# Index of parentNode of an element with javascript

Tags: javascript, indexing

Supposing you have:

```
<div><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p></div>
<div><p id='paragraph'>Some text</p></div>
```

How can you use javascript to find the index of the parent node of id 'paragraph'? I think you have to loop through, with 'docment.getElementsByTagName('div'), but I'm stuck after that. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you need the index of a HTML element inside its parent, you're doing something wrong... The DOM doesn't work like that. (It might, but don't make it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if markup's structure remains the same you could do something like this:

```
var parents = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i=0, length = parents.length, found = false; i < length && !found; i++){
  var parent = parents[i];
  if(parent.querySelector('#paragraph')){//or search for child with that id if IE < 8
    alert('index is '+i);
    found = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you only want to include elements in the index.

```
var node = document.getElementById('paragraph').parentNode,
    i = 0;

while( node = node.previousSibling ) {
    if( node.nodeType === 1 ) {
        i++;
    }
}

alert(i);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dJd6g/

Comment: No point in the `===`. It's always a number. Save the `===` for when they're useful.

Comment: @Rudie: I prefer to standardize my code with `===` and save the `==` for when it's useful (which is rare). Just my preference. :)

Answer (score 0):

I lightly tested this and it should work on most browsers (not sure about IE):

```
var parentIndex = function (id)
{
    var elm = document.getElementById(id);
    var par = elm.parentNode;
    var sib = par.parentNode.childNodes;

    for (var i = 0; i < sib.length; i++)
    {
        if (par == sib[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow the standard of -1 being no match -

```
function indexOf(element) {
    var index = -1;
    while (element) {
        element = element.previousSibling;
        if (element.nodeType === 1) {
            index++;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```